# Save images to folder in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to save an image from the client side to a folder using vb.net

"" the image that has the myImage ID ""

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImage" ImageUrl="http://www.govcomm.harris.com/images/1F-81-imageLinks650a.jpg" />
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImage2" ImageUrl="http://www.govcomm.harris.com/images/2F-81-imageLinks650b.jpg" />
```

this is just the location where i want to save my image : 
i haven't run or try any thing with this code , i am just wondering how to do this 
this location is on the server side

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim saveLocation As String = Server.MapPath("PDFs")
End Sub
```

Also, I would like to know if there is a way to use the id to save since i might have more than one image to be saved.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to save to the client, or to the server?

Comment: Please Be More specify about this Problem so that we can give you better answer....

Comment: i am trying to save this to the server

Comment: And what's happening exactly? Have you debugged to check the mapped path is mapping correctly? Do you get an exception when saving? Does it save somewhere else (wherever the path is mapping to!)? And are you sure you're even trying to save the file (I just see you getting a string, no call to `File` methods)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload a file from the client side (from the user via browser) to the server folder, you need to user the FileUpload control

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

And in your Codebehind, you can save that to a location by Calling the `PostedFile.SaveAs` method

```
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        somefileNameWithExtension="file.pdf" ' Replace this with a a valid file name
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(somefileNameWithExtension)
    End If
```

**EDIT**  : As per the comment

If you want to download a file from the internet, you can do it with the WebClient classes DownloadFile method. Here is an example.

```
    Using webClient As New WebClient()

        Dim targrtFileName = "D:\\myfile.png" ' 
        Dim sourceFile = "http://converter.telerik.com/App_Themes/images/ccHead.png"
        'read the Source of your image control and replace in sourceFile  variable.

        webClient.DownloadFile(sourceFile , targrtFileName)

    End Using
```

Comment: @MinaGabriel: you already have an image where ? in the server ? Are you trying to move that to a different location ?

Comment: not exactly lets say you have an image linked from another web site and you want to save it to your server

Comment: @MinaGabriel : You should have mentioned that when you originally posted your question. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one.....
import System.Net
Dim filepath As String = Server.MapPath(myImage.ImageUrl)

Using client As New WebClient()
client.DownloadFile(filepath, Server.MapPath("Specify the path where you want to    store+imagename"))       //------For  example  client.DownloadFile(filepath,Server.MapPath("~/Image/282.gif"))
End Using
```